# Hibernate Criteria to pull records from OneToMany Relations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am passing a collection of vehicles names like `['car','jeep','truck','bike']` and want to select those owners who owns `vehicles` in this list using Criteria query, Owner here can own multiple `vahicles` (OneToMany). I have a limitation that i need to use Criteria query.

```java
class Owner {

    @ID
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private Long ownerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Set<Vehicles> vehicles;

}

class Vehicles {

    @ID
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Long vehicleId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owner owner;

    @Column(name="vehicle_name")
    private String vehicleName;

}
```

Below is what i have tried but no success

```java
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Owner.class);
criteria.createAlias("vehicles", "vehicles");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("vehicles.vehicleName", setOfVehicles));
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hibernate version is 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your mapping looks incorrect. You have a bidirectional association between `Owner` and `Vehicles`. So, only the `@ManyToOne` side should be annotated by `@JoinColumn`. I will use the corrected in the following way mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Owner
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "own_id")
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
   private Set<Vehicles> vehicles;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Vehicles
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "veh_id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "veh_name")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "veh_own_id")
   private Owner owner;
}
```

Next thing that I have to emphasize, you try to use deprecated Hibernate `org.hibernate.Criteria` [API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria). I am going to provide an example for the [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria). So, the query will have the following view:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Owner> criteria = builder.createQuery(Owner.class);
Root<Owner> root = criteria.from(Owner.class);
SetJoin<Owner, Vehicles> vehs = (SetJoin<Owner, Vehicles>) root.fetch(Owner_.vehicles);

criteria
   .select(root)
   .distinct(true)
   .where(
      vehs.get(Vehicles_.NAME).in(Arrays.asList("car", "jeep", "truck", "bike"))
   );

List<Owner> deps = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

The `Owner_` and `Vehicles_` classes belong to so called [JPA static metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html). Why the casting `(SetJoin<Owner, Vehicles>) root.fetch(Owner_.vehicles)` is necessary described in [this](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-left-join-fetch-join-criteriaquery/) article (see **Defining a JOIN FETCH clause** section).