# Hibernate Criteria API join entities without any association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to write a Hibernate Criteria API equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
select c.NAME         as carName,
   cc.COLOR_CODE      as colorCode,
   cc.COLOR           as color,
   c.DESCRIPTION      as desc,
   c.MANUFACTURE_YEAR as year
from CAR c
     LEFT JOIN CAR_COLOR CC on c.COLOR_CODE_ID = CC.ID
WHERE CC.COLOR_CODE = ?
```

This is my `Car` entity

```
public class Car extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURE_YEAR")
    private String year;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String desc;
    private Long colorCodeId;
    private String manufacturer;
}
```

and this is my `CarColor` entity

```
public class CarColor extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String color;
    private String colorCode;
}
```

`Car.colorCodeId` is a foreign key which references `CarColor.id`. Although there is no apparent entity-level relationship and I cannot add any relationships.

I want to do a left join between these two tables/entities and map the result to `CarSearch`? How would I do this? Much appreciated.

```
public class CarSearch {
    private String carName;
    private String colorCode;
    private String color;
    private String desc;
    private String year;
}
```

Comment: Why you can not add any relationships to your domain model? Usually to be efficient, it should be designed as close as possible to you database tables structure.

Comment: @SternK I suggested them to add relationships, they don't want to! :(

Comment: Using criteria api as well as jpql/hql assume that you have all necessary relationship in your domain model. If you don't have them and you can not add them the only way is using a native query and try to map the output result to the dto classes.

Comment: I have a native query and it works fine. However, they specifically want the Criteria API equivalent.

Comment: They actually want to incrementally build the query - depending on if the where clause expression values are null or otherwise. For example,  building a dynamic query based on fields that a user fills at runtime in a form that contains many optional fields.

Comment: As an example just look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804644/6277104). This is quite similar to your needs. But this query would be impossible without the `@OneToMany` relationship between the entities.

Answer (score 6):

Cartesian product can be used

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Car> car = query.from(Car.class);
Root<CarColor> carColor = query.from(CarColor.class);

Predicate joinPredicate = cb.equal(car.get("colorCodeId"), carColor.get("id"));

query.multiselect(
    car.get("name"),
    carColor.get("colorCode"),
    carColor.get("color"),
    car.get("desc"),
    car.get("year")
).where(
    joinPredicate, 
    cb.equal(carColor.get("colorCode"), "yourColorCode")
);
```

To avoid `Object[]` in query result you should create `QueryResultDto` class with appropriate constructor and use this way

```
CriteriaQuery<QueryResultDto> query = cb.createQuery(QueryResultDto.class);
//...
query.select(cb.construct(QueryResultDto.class, 
    car.get("name"),
    carColor.get("colorCode"),
    carColor.get("color"),
    car.get("desc"),
    car.get("year")
));
```